# Why do username and password return null?

Tags: java

So I have this username and password validation code using Java persistence.

```
public Subscriber validateLogin(String username, String password)
{
   EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Subscriber s WHERE s.username = :username OR s.password = :password ");

    q.setParameter("username", username);
    q.setParameter("password", password);

    try
    {
        return (Subscriber) q.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So I check if the subscriber return anything or `null`. Here is my code:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    SubscriberJpaController sjc = new SubscriberJpaController();
    Subscriber sub = sjc.validateLogin(jTextField1.getText(), jPasswordField1.getText());

    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

and it returns `null`. Anything wrong with my code or logic?

Comment: print the stacktrace before return null in your catch block.

Comment: The only issue I can see is `s.username = :username OR s.password = :password`. Shouldn't this be 'AND'? Otherwise if someone gets the password wrong they will still be logged in.

Comment: iuse AND and its still null. my Subscriber class is an abstract class. any problem with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be an exception thrown when you do the query. you have to print the stacktrace to see the cause.

I guess (not sure) the problem could be at the line `q.getSingleResult();` if other configurations were correctly set.

Jpa is expecting a unique result. however your query could generate a **set** of Subscribers by username=.. **or** password=.... e.g.

```
user a(uname,pwd)= ("usera","123")
user b(uname,pwd)= ("userb","123")
```

so the method getSingleResult() throws the exception.

also, you may consider to use jpa TypedQuery with generic instead of doing the class casting manually.

Comment: yes, the problem is with the q.getSingleResule(), shoud it be q.getResultList()?

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** query on the password.

The query you want to run is this:

`m.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Subscriber s WHERE s.username = :username");`

Once you have received the user, then you check the password validity in code.  This is particularly important because you're obviously hashing your passwords.  Right?

Comment: how did you know OP "obviously" encrypted the pwd?

Comment: @Kent Mark's making a point, not assuming the OP encrypted the password.

Comment: @Mark i follow what you have suggested. still it returns null.

Comment: Set your JPQL environment to print out the SQL statement it is issuing.  Then check to make sure the data is actually there.